# Message or subject are not showing while share with instagram in ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing

Message or subject are not showing while share with instagram in ionic2 ?
using this plugin ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Comment: Which plugin you are using? Add related to your question.

Comment: ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing @SwapnilPatwa

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of plugin. According to
[Plugin's Documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/README.md#instagram)

> Instagram no longer permits prefilling a message.

Quirks:

- Instagram no longer permits prefilling a message - you can prompt the
  user to paste the message you've passed to the plugin because we're
  adding it to the clipboard for you.

iOS Quirks:

- Before trying to invoke shareViaInstagram please use
  canShareVia('instagram'.. AND whitelist the urlscheme (see below).
- Although this plugin follows the Instagram sharing guidelines, the
  user may not only see Instagram in the share sheet, but also other
  apps that listen to the "Instagram sharing ID". Just google
  "com.instagram.exclusivegram" and you see what I mean.